# JDBC driver for Android application

Tags: java, android, jdbc, gradle

I try to add `JDBC` driver as a dependency in an Android project with use of `Gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+'
}
```

I got error message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

I thought, that this is a memory problem, so tried to add code to build.gradle.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Nothing changed, same message again.
`compileSdkVersion` is 18.

Comment: JDBC is not designed to use in android. Use a web service for your connection...see here: http://codeoncloud.blogspot.de/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android